# How to read a file with variable multi-row data in Python

Tags: python

I have a file that is about 100Mb that looks like this:

```
#meta data 1    
skadjflaskdjfasljdfalskdjfl
sdkfjhasdlkgjhsdlkjghlaskdj
asdhfk
#meta data 2
jflaksdjflaksjdflkjasdlfjas
ldaksjflkdsajlkdfj
#meta data 3
alsdkjflasdjkfglalaskdjf
```

This file contains one row of meta data that corresponds to several, variable length data containing only alpha-numeric characters. What is the best way to read this data into a simple list like this:

```
data = [[#meta data 1, skadjflaskdjfasljdfalskdjflsdkfjhasdlkgjhsdlkjghlaskdjasdhfk],
       [#meta data 2, jflaksdjflaksjdflkjasdlfjasldaksjflkdsajlkdfj],
       [#meta data 3, alsdkjflasdjkfglalaskdjf]]
```

My initial idea was to use the `read()` method to read the whole file into memory and then use regular expressions to parse the data into the desired format. Is there a better more pythonic way? All metadata lines start with an octothorpe and all data lines are all alpha-numeric. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) provides an easy way to collect lines into groups:

```
import itertools

data=[]
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    for key,group in itertools.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('#meta')):
        if key:
            meta=next(group).strip()
        else:
            lines=''.join(group).strip()
            data.append((meta,lines))
print(data)
```

yields

```
[('#meta data 1', 'skadjflaskdjfasljdfalskdjfl\nsdkfjhasdlkgjhsdlkjghlaskdj\nasdhfk'), ('#meta data 2', 'jflaksdjflaksjdflkjasdlfjas\nldaksjflkdsajlkdfj'), ('#meta data 3', 'alsdkjflasdjkfglalaskdjf')]
```

---

The expression

```
itertools.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('#meta'))
```

returns an iterator. It loops through the lines in `f`, and calls the `lambda` function on each line. When it encounters a line that begins with `#meta`, that function returns `True`, otherwise `False`.

`itertools.groupby` collects all the contiguous lines that return the same value.

So the line that begins with `#meta` is placed in its own group, then all the subsequent lines not beginning with `#meta` are placed in the next group, and so on.

The `key` is the return value from the `lambda` function. In this case, it will be either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Wow this is great! The only thing I'm having difficulty with is my output gives me `[(False, 'skadjflaskdjfasljdfalskdjfl\nsdkfjhasdlkgjhsdlkjghlaskdj\nasdhfk')...` I can't seem to see why I get a boolean and why it is false?!

Comment: It looks like perhaps you are printing the `key` rather than `meta`? Are you using `data.append((key,lines))`? If so, change `key` --> `meta`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will be the fastest way, but from the top of my head:

```
data = []
with open('input.file', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '#':
            data.append((line, []))
        else:
            data[-1][1].append(line)
data = [(X, ''.join(Y)) for X, Y in data]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a cool answer. I've never thought to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like that:

```
result = []
for line in file.readlines():
    if line[0] == '#':
        result.append([line])
    else:
        if len(result[-1]) == 1:
            result[-1].append(line)
        else:
            result[-1][-1] += line
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple, something like:

```
data = [] # result
lastmeta = None # the last metadata line seen
chunks = [] # lines since the last metadata line
for line in input:
    if line[0] == '#': # metadata
        if lastmeta: # need to flush data we've collected
            data.append((lastmeta, ''.join(chunks))
        lastmeta = line
    else:
        chunks.append(line)
```